# Data Set is empty but Table and rows says 1

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, dataset, visual-studio-2005

I am populating a Dataset from mssql, the problem I am having is that when I go to check the Table count and the Row Count to see if it is empty they both return a value Greater then 0 which should mean they are not empty but when I try to access them they are empty.. and they should be empty because to test this I emptied the table I am hitting.

Here is My code

```
Dim da As OdbcDataAdapter
Dim dsProNum As New DataSet
ssql = "SELECT * FROM ProNumberEXP WHERE BillTo = ? and ShipTo = ?"
    Try
        da = New OdbcDataAdapter(ssql, Me.connString)
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@BillTo", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = BillTo.Trim
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ShipTo", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = ShipTo.Trim
        da.Fill(dsProNum)

    Catch ex As Exception
        dsProNum = Nothing
        return False
    End Try
    If dsProNum.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then
        Found = False
    Else
        Found = True
    End If
    dsProNum = Nothing
```

My If statement, `If dsProNum.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then` always returns false regardless of what is in the table I am pulling from.

can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Where is the code that creates the DataSet? And why do you use the ODBC adapter instead of SqlDataAdapter?

Comment: Hi use better a datatable

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos Added the code that creates the DataSet.  I'm not sure on the original choice for the ODBC adapter over the SQLData Adapter as I inherited the program and I am modifying the existing code.  I think it's because we use ODBC DSN's for all our DB Connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the code that creates the DataSet I can only guess that you created the DataSet with a DataTable before filling it or that you used a designer to create it, in which case it already has a table.

Instead of checking whether the DataSet has any tables, you should check the return value of [DbDataAdapter.Fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxkb3c3d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Fill returns the number of rows actually added or updated in the dataset.

You should also consider using [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead of OdbcDataAdapter as it is much faster and supports more SQL Server features.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this out now with the .fill